# Transfer MSSQL table to In-Memory OLTP technique without timestamp column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

As MS SQL Server Express 2016 offers the new In-Memory OLTP for free, I want to transfer my tables to the new technique. Doing this, I have a problem, because I'm using timestamp-columns to find out the newest data set of a person - e.g. the newest email address.

To demonstrate the problem, you'll neet to generate 3 tables. The first one for persons:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[persons](
[Pers_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Pers_surname] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Pers_forename] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Pers_birthdate] [datetime] NULL,
[Pers_last_change] [datetime] NULL,
[Pers_changed_by] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Pers_Timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_persons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Pers_ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,     
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The second one for email addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emailadress](
[Email_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Email_adress] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Email_up_to_date] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Email_last_change] [datetime] NULL,
[Email_changed_by] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Email_Timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_emailadress] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([Email_ID] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[emailadress] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[DF_emailadress_up_to_date]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Email_up_to_date]
GO
```

The last one for the link between the two first tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersEmail](
[PersEmail_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Pers_ID] [int] NULL,
[Email_ID] [int] NULL,
[PersEmail_out_of_date] [bit] NOT NULL,
[PersEmail_last_change] [datetime] NULL,
[PersEmail_changed_by] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[PersEmail_Timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_PersEmail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([PersEmail_ID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

Every person could have several email adresses and one email adress could be linked to several persons. There is an trigger which set the connection out of date if the email address is out of date.

For a lot of reports I just need one email adress of the persons. This should be the newest email adress. To find out, which is the newest, I use the timestamp column:

```
SELECT P.Pers_ID, Pers_surname, Pers_forename, Pers_birthdate, 
PersEmail_ID, Email_adress

FROM persons P

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM dbo.PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0) AS PE 
ON PE.Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM dbo.emailadress WHERE Email_up_to_date = 1) AS email 
ON email.Email_ID = PE.Email_ID

WHERE P.Pers_ID = @intID AND

((PE.PersEmail_Timestamp IS NULL) OR
(PE.PersEmail_Timestamp = ( SELECT MAX(PersEmail_Timestamp) AS Expr1
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0) AS 
persemail2
WHERE       Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID)))

RETURN
```

I tried to use an datetime2(7) column instead of the timestamp column. But it is possible that the person has two email addresses changed with an "Update" statement at once. The datetime2 column now will contain two identical datetimes. Then my query will show two lines instead of one. In comparison the timestamp column delivers two different contents and my query delivers just one line as wished.

Does anyone know how to replace the timestamp columns for the descriped goal?

If there is independently of the In-Memory-Question an suggestion to improve the query to find out the newest email address, please let me know also.

Note: I hope the above quoted code is correct. I translated the column names from german and tried to use english versions instead. The original code will work fine... just let me know if I overlooked a fault.

At last this Code seems to work for me, but I'm not sure, wheter it is the best:

```
SELECT      P.Pers_ID, Pers_surname, Pers_forename, Pers_birthdate, 
PE.PersEmail_ID, Email_adress

FROM        persons P

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0) AS PE 
ON  PE.Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM emailadress WHERE Email_up_to_date = 1) AS email ON 
email.Email_ID = PE.Email_ID

WHERE       P.Pers_ID = @intID AND

((PE.PersEmail_TS IS NULL) OR
(PE.PersEmail_ID =  (   SELECT TOP 1    PersEmail_ID
FROM        (SELECT * FROM dbo.PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0) 
AS persemail3       
WHERE       Pers_ID = @intID

AND PersEmail_TS = (    SELECT      MAX(PersEmail_TS) AS Expr1
FROM        (SELECT * FROM dbo.PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0)  
AS persemail2
WHERE       Pers_ID = @intID))))
```

Comment: If you update two rows at once, then a solution using `timestamp` gives you *an* updated row, with no guarantee of which one. If that's sufficient, then you shouldn't worry about two rows having the same `datetime2` either -- just consistently use an additional column as a tiebreaker (like the `id`) in a `TOP(1)`.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by making your tables in-memory?

Comment: It should be faster than before. Isn't there an performance-boost by the new technic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked at last for me. Thanks for the hint with "TOP 1":

```
SELECT      P.Pers_ID, PE.PersEmail_ID, PE.Email_ID, Email_Adress

FROM        persons P

            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT * FROM PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0) AS PE ON  PE.Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID 

            INNER JOIN
            (   SELECT      * 
                FROM        emailadress
                WHERE       Email_up_to_date = 1
            )   AS E ON E.Email_ID = PE.Email_ID

  WHERE     (P.Pers_ID = @intID OR @intID=0)

        AND

            ((PE.PersEmail_TS IS NULL) OR
            (PE.PersEmail_ID =  (   SELECT TOP 1    PersEmail_ID
                                    FROM        (SELECT * FROM dbo.PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_inaktuell = 0) AS persemail3       
                                    WHERE       Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID
                                            AND PersEmail_TS = (    SELECT      MAX(PersEmail_TS) AS Expr1
                                                                    FROM        (SELECT * FROM dbo.PersEmail WHERE PersEmail_out_of_date = 0) AS persemail2
                                                                    WHERE       Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you update two email addresses for the same person in one UPDATE statement, then there is no guarantee which one of these email addresses will receive the highest timestamp. @Jeroen Mostert also mentioned this in a comment.

When you are moving to In-Memory OLTP (where the timestamp data type is not supported) it should be fine to use a datetime2(7) column. You would have to make a minor change to your query to ensure that you do not receive multiple rows.

One suggestion of a query rewrite would be this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    P.Pers_ID, Pers_surname, Pers_forename, Pers_birthdate, PersEmail_ID, Email_adress
FROM persons P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PersEmail PE 
        ON PE.Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID 
        AND PE.PersEmail_inaktuell = 0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.emailadress email 
        ON email.Email_ID = PE.Email_ID 
        AND email.Email_up_to_date = 1
WHERE P.Pers_ID = @intID 
ORDER BY PE.PersEmail_Timestamp DESC, PE.Email_ID DESC
```

This query still ensures that you only receive 1 record, and that the received record is one of the latest updated records. I.e. if two or more records in your PersEmail table were updated in the same UPDATE statement, then you will receive the one with the highest Email_ID.

Comment: I can't use the "ORDER BY"-Statement, because I have also the postal adress, bank account, phone number eg. which has to be selected (always the newes one) as by the email address.

But it should work for me with "TOP 1". If two email addresses had the same "last change"-time there is no difference between the importance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you cannot use the ORDER BY. Did you manage to get it working? :-)

Comment: I tried to describe the problem as easy as possible. In the database there is not only a table for email adress, but also for postal adress. And for phone-number eg.

If I want to have an overview over the persons actual email-adress, postal adress, phone-number e.g. I have some more "LEFT OUTER JOIN" to that tables.

It is like

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PersTel PT
    ON PT.Pers_ID = P.Pers_ID 
    AND PE.Perstel_out_of_date = 0

Because of that extra tables, I cannot ORDER BY just one of them (or I can do that, but it will not help with the others).